# AFNetworking's AFHTTPClient how to debug the http request?

Tags: ios, logging, httpwebrequest, sinatra, afnetworking

I'm having trouble getting AFNetworking to communicate successfully with a web service. Is there a way to log out (or view in some other way) the exact http request that it is sending?

Answer (score 7):

You should check out [AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger), which listens for the notifications sent when operations start and finish, and log them out with configurable verbosity.

Comment: I don't see the post data attached via AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

I really like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) for watching network traffic when using the simulator.

Comment: Too bad its a trial version. Was looking for an alternate for Fiddler.

Comment: It's not a trial app if you buy it.